# Bootstrap Forms

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking how a bootstrap form looks like, And I saw something that looks pretty much like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputA">Some Input:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Input" id="inputA" class="form-control">
</div>
```

And it's really bothers me to do the `for` attribute every time. so, my question is, Is it possible to do somethig like this?:

```
<label class="form-group">
    <span>Some Input:</span>
    <input type="text" name="Input" id="inputA" class="form-control">
</label>
```

And is there any possible issues working this way?

Answer (score 0):

The `for` simply toggles the control for the form input. Essentially, when you click the label, the form element is focused upon, or selected, depending on what type of form element it is. You do not have to include the `for` on each label; however, this is just common practice. I would not swap the `label` for a `span` though, I would simply do this...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foo">
    </div>
</div>
```